# Why does trying to set "points" via Python properties cause infinite recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, decorator, getter-setter

Why does trying to set “points” via Python properties cause infinite recursion?

**Using Python 3**

```
import Task

myTask = Task.Task("Test",-5)

myTask.points = -7

print(myTask)
```

---

```
class Task:

def __init__(self,name="",points=0,times_done=0):
    self.name = name
    self.points = points
    self.times_done = times_done

@property
def points(self):
    return self.points

@points.setter
def points(self, points):
    if (points < 0):
        self.points = 0
    else:
        self.points = points

def __str__(self):
    return "The task '" + self.name + "' is worth " + str(self.points) + " and has been completed " + str(self.times_done) + " times."
```

---

When it tries constructing it with value -5 (which should set it to 0, via the property), it infinitely recurses on the line `self.points = points` in the setter function/decoration `@points.setter.`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error. Are you omitting any code here?

Comment: Only stuff that shouldn't be related at all. I'll edit it

Comment: @Julien, OP should be using Python 3.x. If you're using python 2.x, by inheriting from `object`, you can reproduce: `class Task(object)`.

Comment: I'm using Python 3, yeah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `self.points = ...` call the setter; inside the setter, `self.points = ...` is executed which call the setter; recursion repeated until stack overflow.

By using other name, you can prevent the recursion: `self._points` for example.

Or instead of using `self.points = ...`, use `self.__dict__['points'] = ..` (same for getter):

```
@property
def points(self):
    return self.__dict__['points']

@points.setter
def points(self, points):
    if points < 0:
        self.__dict__['points'] = 0
    else:
        self.__dict__['points'] = points
    # self.__dict__['points'] = max(0, points)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because inside your `property setter`, it calls itself again:

```
@points.setter
def points(self, points):
    if (points < 0):
        self.points = 0 # call itself again here
    else:
        self.points = points # call itself again here
```

You need another field to store the actually value when you use `property`, and it would be better to be a `"private" field`:

```
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self,name="",points=0,times_done=0):
            self.name = name
            self.points = points
            self.times_done = times_done

    @property
    def points(self):
            return self._points

    @points.setter
    def points(self, points):
            if (points < 0):
                    self._points = 0
            else:
                    self._points = points
```